# I want to pick values from spark dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i have a spark dataframe

```
vehicle_Coalence ECU       asIs modelPart codingPart Flag
12321123         VDAF206  A297 A214      A114        0
12321123         VDAF206  A297 A215      A115        0
12321123         VDAF205  A296 A216      A116        0
12321123         VDAF205  A298 A217      A117        0
12321123         VDAF207  A299 A218      A118        1
12321123         VDAF207  A300 A219      A119        2
12321123         VDAF208  A299 A218      A118        1
12321123         VDAF208  A300 A219      A119        2
12321123         VDAF208  A300 A219      A119        0
```

w = Window.partitionBy('vehicle_coalesce', 'ecu')
i want to pick all the values where the partition dosent have Flag="0"

i want output in this case

```
vehicle_Coalence ECU       asIs modelPart codingPart Flag
12321123         VDAF207  A299 A218       A218       1
12321123         VDAF207  A300 A219       A219       2
```

i tried couple of things but it didnt work

Comment: Hi, please check my answer to see if it works as your intended

Comment: Have you tried filtering out all records that have flag = 0 first?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to Filter out only the necessary value first then use join like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

# Define the data
data = [(12321123, "VDAF206", "A297", "A214", "A114", 0),
        (12321123, "VDAF206", "A297", "A215", "A115", 0),
        (12321123, "VDAF205", "A296", "A216", "A116", 0),
        (12321123, "VDAF205", "A298", "A217", "A117", 0),
        (12321123, "VDAF207", "A299", "A218", "A118", 1),
        (12321123, "VDAF207", "A300", "A219", "A119", 2),
        (12321123, "VDAF208", "A299", "A218", "A118", 1),
        (12321123, "VDAF208", "A300", "A219", "A119", 2),
        (12321123, "VDAF208", "A300", "A219", "A119", 0)]

# Create original DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["vehicle_coalesce", "ecu", "asIs", "modelPart", "codingPart", "Flag"])
df.show()
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+
# |vehicle_coalesce|    ecu|asIs|modelPart|codingPart|Flag|
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+
# |        12321123|VDAF206|A297|     A214|      A114|   0|
# |        12321123|VDAF206|A297|     A215|      A115|   0|
# |        12321123|VDAF205|A296|     A216|      A116|   0|
# |        12321123|VDAF205|A298|     A217|      A117|   0|
# |        12321123|VDAF207|A299|     A218|      A118|   1|
# |        12321123|VDAF207|A300|     A219|      A119|   2|
# |        12321123|VDAF208|A299|     A218|      A118|   1|
# |        12321123|VDAF208|A300|     A219|      A119|   2|
# |        12321123|VDAF208|A300|     A219|      A119|   0|
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+

# Try to filter the vehicle_coalesce and ecu that doesn't contain 0 in Flag
dfFilter = df.groupBy('vehicle_coalesce', 'ecu').agg(min("Flag"))
dfFilter.show()
# +----------------+-------+---------+
# |vehicle_coalesce|    ecu|min(Flag)|
# +----------------+-------+---------+
# |        12321123|VDAF206|        0|
# |        12321123|VDAF205|        0|
# |        12321123|VDAF207|        1|
# |        12321123|VDAF208|        0|
# +----------------+-------+---------+

dfFilter = dfFilter.filter(col("min(Flag)") != 0)
dfFilter.show()
# +----------------+-------+---------+
# |vehicle_coalesce|    ecu|min(Flag)|
# +----------------+-------+---------+
# |        12321123|VDAF207|        1|
# +----------------+-------+---------+

# Join the original df with Filter df on vehicle_coalesce and ecu column. Select only neccessary col
resultDF = df.alias("dfOriginal").join(dfFilter, (df.vehicle_coalesce == dfFilter.vehicle_coalesce) & (df.ecu == dfFilter.ecu)) \
        .select("dfOriginal.*")

resultDF.show()
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+
# |vehicle_coalesce|    ecu|asIs|modelPart|codingPart|Flag|
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+
# |        12321123|VDAF207|A299|     A218|      A118|   1|
# |        12321123|VDAF207|A300|     A219|      A119|   2|
# +----------------+-------+----+---------+----------+----+
```